# Move email after being categorized

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to move emails, once they are categorized, into a folder with the same name as the category.

What I found so far:

```
Private WithEvents Explorer As Outlook.Explorer
Private WithEvents Mail As Outlook.MailItem
Private MoveToThisFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Friend Sub Application_Startup()
  On Error Resume Next
  Set Explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub Explorer_SelectionChange()
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim Sel As Outlook.Selection

  Set Mail = Nothing
  Set Sel = Explorer.Selection

  If Sel.Count > 0 Then
    Set obj = Sel(1)
    If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.MailItem Then
      Set Mail = obj
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Mail_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim SubfolderName As String

  If Name = "Categories" Then
    Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    SubfolderName = Mail.Categories
    If Len(SubfolderName) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Set Subfolder = Inbox.Folders(SubfolderName)
    If Subfolder.EntryID <> Mail.Parent.EntryID Then
      Set MoveToThisFolder = Subfolder
      EnableTimer 500, Me
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Friend Sub TimerEvent()
  DisableTimer
  If Mail Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If MoveToThisFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Mail.Move MoveToThisFolder
  Set Mail = Nothing
  Set MoveToThisFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have some problems with respect to `Friend Sub TimerEvent ()` because it gives me

> Sub or Function not compiled correctly

Answer (score 0):

At the end i figured out in this way:

```
    Private WithEvents xInboxFld As Outlook.Folder
Private WithEvents xInboxItems As Outlook.Items
 
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set xInboxFld = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set xInboxItems = xInboxFld.Items
End Sub
 
Private Sub xInboxItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xFlds As Outlook.Folders
Dim xFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim xTargetFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim xFlag As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
If Item.Class = olMail Then
    Set xMailItem = Item
    xFlag = False
    If xMailItem.Categories <> "" Then
        Set xFlds = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
        If xFlds.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each xFld In xFlds
                If xFld.Name = xMailItem.Categories Then
                    xFlag = True
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If xFlag = False Then
            Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders.Add xMailItem.Categories, olFolderInbox
        End If
        Set xTargetFld = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(xMailItem.Categories)
        xMailItem.Move xTargetFld
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Hope it could help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to missing code for `DisableTimer` and `EnableTimer`.

The category has not yet updated when the code is triggered.

`EnableTimer` delays the move until after the category updates.

Without a delay, there would be an error when attempting to update, due to the item having been moved.

Attribution: http://www.vboffice.net/en/developers/trigger-actions-with-categories/